# Video won't play in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, video, sharepoint-2013

We have SharePoint 2013. We have uploaded several videos into our Media library. When I am looking at all the videos in the library and click on one, I receive this error:

*Sorry, something went wrong 
Could not load the assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.*

But if I click on the ellipsis of the video(. . .) and click play... it plays just fine.

But the problem is we provide the link on our site and when our users are clicking on that link it is spitting out that error above. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It has to do with the registered assemblies in the videoplayerpage.aspx form referencing Version 16 assemblies of Microsoft.SharePoint. As far as I can tell these versions are only used in Office 365 (as of today's post). I found this out when I tried migrating another page layout from an office 365 site to an on-prem site.

Anyways, I found a workaround to get the page to at least display and play the video. It's not the best solution because you'd have to update every page and library manually. Or you could write a ps script to copy the updated file to each media library.

Also, I'm not sure if in a future update Microsoft would overwrite these files. So just be aware.

Open SharePoint designer and navigate to your library. Then navigate to Forms>Video>videoplayerpage.aspx. Edit in advanced mode and replace all the Register tags with this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs2" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs1" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs0" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"  inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"     %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="OfficeServer" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointPortalWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointTaxonomy" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```